# how to control a console oppened in terminal using python

Tags: python, automation, raspberry-pi

so, i've been trying to make an automated program that do everything i need to open yowsup(a whatapp robot).
i need a programe that will open terminal and start yowsup(it is a code that when its open in terminal it start a consle([PHOTO1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV4Rj.png)). what i've done so far is a very very basci code in python to put a command in terminal to start yowsup,but when yousup is started (after "os.system("yowsup-cli demos....")) the resp of my code does not do what i was expecting(i was expecting to write "/L" in yowsup console) but it doeen't. what happen is: it starts normally yowsup console and it stays there, waiting for me to write manually a command(the same as 1.[PHOTO1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XscJL.png)), and when i press "CTRL"+ c to close yowsups's console it turns back  in to  linux terminal, and in that linux terminal it asks for an input(SEE PHOTHO 3 [PIC3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecU8z.png))because what realy is happening is it runs the command to open yowsup console and it runs the command input in terminal **BUT** since the terminal is ocupped with yowsup's console it waits untill i close it to run the rest of my code, i want a solution that will permit me to write in yowsup's console, not to wait until the console is gone and then write the code in terminal. I hope everything is clear now

```
import os
import subprocess as sub

os.system ("cd yowsup")
os.system ("yowsup-cli demos -y -c /home/pi/yowsup/d.conf")


a = raw_input('numero: ')

m = raw_imput('mensagem: ')

os.system("/L")
os.system("/message send", a ,"m")
```

PS. I'm running python 2.7.6 in a raspberry pi3(raspian, linux)

Comment: this question is somewhat too broad. Please come up with a definition of a specific problem, what you've tried so far, why it didn't work.

Comment: recently i've edited!! chek it out